# need help removing win10 and keeping linux

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, manjaro

I have a question that I'm sure someone on here can answer. i am dual booting windows 10 and manjaro linux and what i want to do is delete windows and keep linux on here but the problem i'm having is windows is on sda2 and linux is on sda5 and what i want to do is delete the windows partition and join the partitions together but i have a feeling that if i do that, linux won't boot because it's on sda5. i'm trying to figure out some way to work this because i have manjaro exactly how i want it and i don't want to have to reinstall it and do all of this over again. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, joining the partitions would be very complicated.

What would be easier is to format `sda2` as ext4 and mount it in your Linux mount table separately. However, Windows (often) uses a separate partition for its boot-loaders - which is about 100MB or so. You can find it in the partition table of your drive. Merging this (small) partition with your `sda2` main Windows partition should easily be possible.

But take care of where your current [MBR (Master boot record)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is located on your drive. Windows is very possessive in that regard. So after removing Windows, you'll have to reinstall a new MBR (classic or GUID) which points to your `sda5` Linux partition. So after removing Windows, you'll have to reinstall a new boot-loader with `grub`.

Doing all of the above is not simple - and errors will not be easily forgiven. So I recommend a backup of all critical data before attempting this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, first **make a complete backup of your data and then verify it matches what's on your system's drive**.

You can remove the Windows NTFS partition and reassign its space to an **adjacent** partition. However, Windows often has more than one partition, and please be careful not to remove the EFI partition or /boot.

Another critical issue is, where's [GRUB2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB)? If the GRUB2 configuration is lost, you won't be able to complete booting after removing the Windows partition(s).  If you run mount and see something like this:

/dev/sda5 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,stripe=4,data=ordered)

You have grub2 installed in its own partition, as it should be.